# elasticsearch - No query registered for [query]]

Tags: java, groovy, elasticsearch

I am trying to send request to ES from my tests. [I applied mapping and inserted documents to ES index named 'gccount_test' from the same test](https://github.com/iPrayag/gccount/blob/master/test/unit/eccount/TransactionServiceTests.groovy#L29). I have a very simple query maintained in a file named `member` that I want to test.

```
{
    "query" : { 
          "match_all" : {} 
     }
}
```

My test method is

```
public void testMemberQuery(){
        final Charset CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8

        //load query
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(MEMBER_QUERY_PATH))
        String query = CHARSET.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)).toString()

        println "QUERY => ${query}"

        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
        searchSourceBuilder.query(query)

        SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
        //ClusterAdminClient adminClient = client.admin().cluster()
        //searchRequestBuilder.setTypes(Constants.ESTYPE_MEMBER)
        //println "CLUSTER => ${adminClient}"

        searchRequestBuilder.setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH);
        searchRequestBuilder.internalBuilder(searchSourceBuilder)

        SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet()
        println "Search Response => ${searchResponse.toString()}"

        //blah blah 
    }
```

Unfortunately, I get following error.

```
Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], total failure; shardFailures {[1][gccount][0]: SearchParseException[[gccount_test][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query_binary":"ewogICAgInF1ZXJ5IiA6IHsgCiAgICAgICAgICAibWF0Y2hfYWxsIiA6IHt9IAogICAgIH0KfQ=="}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[gccount_test] No query registered for [query]]; }
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], total failure; shardFailures {[1][gccount_test][0]: SearchParseException[[gccount_test][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query_binary":"ewogICAgInF1ZXJ5IiA6IHsgCiAgICAgICAgICAibWF0Y2hfYWxsIiA6IHt9IAogICAgIH0KfQ=="}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[gccount_test] No query registered for [query]]; }
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:261)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$3.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:214)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteFetch(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:246)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryAndFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryAndFetchAction.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:206)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am using elasticsearch 0.90.2 dependecy

```
[group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '0.90.2']
```

Same thing runs fine in real environment(snapshot below)

[image]

Is the problem with while loading query from file that caused it's malformation or what?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The exception basically means "There is no known query type called `query`".  I'm guessing that your client library is automatically inserting the top-level `query` property, so your generated query actually looks like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "query" : { 
          "match_all" : {} 
        }
    }
}
```

If your client can dump the JSON representation of the query, that can help a lot in debugging.

Try removing the `query` portion from your text file so that it is just the `match_all` query, see if that works for you.

Comment: ES also ships with a validation api you can use to debug malformed queries http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html

Answer (score 0):

your query string should be

```java
String query = "{\"match_all\":{}}";
```

you can see from here

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/parsingexception-in-elastic-5-0-0/64626