# Elasticsearch: how to do filtered search and aggregation at the same time

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to do a filtered search plus aggregation the following way, conceptually.

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query": { 
                "match_all" : {
                }
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "facets": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "subject"
                }
            }
        },
        "filter" : {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The above query is not working because I got the following error message:

```
[filtered] query does not support [aggregations]]
```

I was trying to solve this problem. I found Filter Aggregation or Filters Aggregation online, but they do not seem to address my need.

Could someone show me the structure of the correct query that can achieve my goal?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of aggregation is the query and all the filters in it. Which means if you give the aggregation along with the query in normal fashion , it should work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {}
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "facets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "subject"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Vineeth, I got the following parsing error: QueryParsingException[[myIndex] No query registered for [query]]. I followed the structure you posted and json query string is valid. Any quick idea of what may be wrong?

Comment: Vineeth, i am looking at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167976/elasticsearch-no-query-registered-for-query

Comment: Vineeth, I ran a command line search instead of search from within my Java program. Your structure works. I posted another question for my current problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027621/elasticsearch-how-to-prevent-my-client-from-automatically-inserting-the-top-lev

Could you please take a look at it?