# Elasticsearch: how to prevent my client from automatically inserting the top-level query property

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to generate a query string with the following structure:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
       ....
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "facets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "subject"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the following client for search:

```
Client client = new TransportClient(my_settings_object)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", "9200"));
SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("my_index")
        .setTypes("my_doctype")
        .setQuery(query) ; // this is above query string built manually
        .execute().actionGet();         
return sr;
```

I got the following error:

```
QueryParsingException[[my_idex] No query registered for [query]]
```

It seems that this error is explained in this SO post:

[elasticsearch - No query registered for [query]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167976/elasticsearch-no-query-registered-for-query)

Basically, my client automatically inserts the top-level query property to make it look like:

```
{
    query:  {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "filter": {
           ....
          }
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "facets": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "subject"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

How can I prevent my client from automatically inserting the top-level query property?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your query and aggregations query individaul JSON objects. Change the query to:

```
{
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {

            }
        },
        "filter": {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

And change the aggregations so that they are in individual JSON object:

```
    {
        "facets": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "subject"
            }
        }
    }
```

Set the query and aggregations in the SearchRequestBuilder:

```
SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("my_index")
    .setTypes("my_doctype")
    .setQuery(query) ; // this is above query string built manually
    .setAggregations(aggregations.getBytes());
    .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Hello Dan, I am trying your method. I googled and cannot seem to find examples how to build BytesReference object out of a string. I believe your approach should work, but setAggregations(aggregations) requires a BytesReference  object. Do you happen to have any links for creating BytesReference  object out of a string? Or update your answer with creating a BytesReference  object?  Thanks!!!

Comment: Just convert the string to bytes: aggregationsJson.getBytes()

Comment: Dan, I tried it, and there was a compilation error. aggregations_string.getBytes() returns byte[], which is not BytesReference. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The `setAggregations` method accepts a byte array as a parameter `public SearchRequestBuilder setAggregations(byte[] aggregations) {`, in the `SearchRequestBuilder` class in the Elasticsearch source code. So you shouldn't be getting a compilation error. What version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: The `BytesArray` class in Elasticsearch implements the `BytesReference` interface, so you can set the aggregations like this: `searchRequestBuilder.setAggregations(new BytesArray(aggregationsJsonAsString));`

Comment: That works! Sorry that I dont anything about this ES class. Cheers!

Comment: Dan, I made change to your aggregation string. Because of using setAggregations method, there is no need for the outer "aggregations" property.

Answer (score 1):

How do you build the `query` object in your Java code?

Try using `QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(...)` to prepare it : the result will be wrapped in the `query` attribute when you call the related setter of the SearchRequestBuilder.

Comment: Thomas, I build my query manually this way: query = "{ query: " + query_string + "," + aggregation_string + "}" . I have a quite complex filtered query and I hope to keep using.